# Cookies not set using apollo-client, apollo-server and express-session

Tags: reactjs, cookies, apollo-client, apollo-server, express-session

I'm trying to initialize cookie on login using express-session but it only seem to be working  am requesting from same site.

Apollo-Client:

```
 const endPoint = createUploadLink({
    uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql'
})

const client  = new ApolloClient({
   link: endPoint,
   credentials: 'include',
   cache: new InMemoryCache(),
 })
```

Apollo-server:

```
 const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  credentials: true,
  allowedHeaders: ['Content-Type', 'Authorization']
}
app.use(session({
  name: 'foo',
  secret: 'bar',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  cookie: {
    maxAge: 360000,
    sameSite: 'none',
    httpOnly: true
  }
}))

const apolloServer = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  playground: {
    settings: {
      'request.credentials': 'include'
    }
  },
  cors: corsOptions

});
```

Now if request is made via graphql playground the cookies is set but if login request is made from localhost:3000 and session initialized no cookie is set.

Please am I missing here.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const client = new ApolloClient({
  link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
  cache,

  fetchOptions: {
    credentials: "include",
  }
})
```

its working for me ...try this

Comment: also if you are using old version of Apollo playground just edit the settings: `"request.credentials": "include"`